# How can I get the credentials associated with the attached EC2 IAM role using the Java v2 SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services

In V1 SDK, we can use `EC2MetadataUtils.getIAMSecurityCredentials();` to get the temporary security credentials associated with the IAM roles on the instance.

```
Map<String, EC2MetadataUtils.IAMSecurityCredential> credMap = EC2MetadataUtils.getIAMSecurityCredentials();
```

What's the equivalent in the V2 SDK?

I can't find anything in the dev guides or on Stack Overflow.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `EC2MetadataUtils` class also exists in the AWS SDK for Java v2.

`getIAMSecurityCredentials` is documented [here](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/2.0.0/software/amazon/awssdk/regions/internal/util/EC2MetadataUtils.html#getIamSecurityCredentials).

```java
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.internal.util.EC2MetadataUtils;

Map<String, EC2MetadataUtils.IAMSecurityCredential> credMap = EC2MetadataUtils.getIAMSecurityCredentials();
```

Comment: OK thanks, checking this but my dependency doesn't have the internal class for some reason (software.amazon.awssdk.regions.internal.util.EC2MetadataUtils) v2.17.160

Comment: Tried upgrading to a few more versions e.g. .209. Simply not there despite being in the documentation. What the .. am I doing wrong? EDIT: OK found it finally in v2.9.9

Comment: Maybe better to start a new thread but new problem - now in this version there are more missing classes. Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: software.amazon.awssdk.regions.ServiceMetadataAdvancedOption

Comment: @orion_kid Please create a new question